# Pairwise disjoint family of sets

Tags: analysis

Let $\{ (a_n , b_n) \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a pairwise disjont family of open intervals. We choose for any $(a_n , b_n )$a closed interval $[a'_{n} , b'_{n} ]$ such that $$b'_n - a'_n = \frac{b_n-a_n}{c}$$
where $c>1$. How to prove that for any $x \in [a'_{n} , b'_{n} ]$ there exists an open interval $J_x$ such that $x \in J_x \in (a_n , b_n)$. Please help me.

Comment: I don't think this holds. Unless you require $[a_n',b_n']\subset(a_n,b_n)$. And then I don't see why you summon more than one interval

Comment: You don't require $a_n < a'_n $ or $b'_n < b_n$; do you mean to? If so, the result is straightforward.